# Lightning component button in Lightning list view

Tags: lightning, lightninglistview

I have a requirement where in a list view of the Custom object, user can select multiple records and click a custom button.On click of this button, lightning component needs to open and ID of the selected records needs to be obtained in this lightning component. Could anyone please let me know how to achieve this in lightning?

Comment: I tried to create lightning action and invoke component.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this with Lightning Component only. You could look into using a visualforce page with lightning out for your lightning component. The visualforce page will allow you to use the StandartSetController.getSelected() method in order to get the selected record Ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue to add a custom lightning component used as a button to list view. What I learnt that Salesforce has a limitation with adding the lightning component as a button on the list view. You can add a quick action of type create a record type on list view but not those quick action having the content source as a custom lightning component.

Finally, I ended with list button of type URL where I called my VF page and added it to search layout.